# Time spent writing cutting and rendering map tiles algorithm/mechanism

Tags: tiles, maps, google

I know this a very vague question but I really need to know this.

Can anyone help me find kinda matrix that shows how much time spent by different companies writing their map tile cutters/renderers like Google,Bing,Yahoo, OpenStreetMap, Maptiler, Mapnik (at the heart of TileMill) and Geoserver tile rendering system.

Since I need to make a rough estimate that if I start writing the entire tile cutting and rendering mechanism in house then how much time,resources and money do I need.

Answer (score 2):

You question is vague and there is a high probability that private companies will never publicly state anything about their investments in their core software stack.

That said, for opensource software, you can use OpenHub to get a rough estimate of the software value thanks to the COCOMO method.

Note that OpenStreetMap uses (among other tools) Mapnik for rendering.

Here is Mapnik ( 52 years ) :
https://www.openhub.net/p/mapnik

Here is Geoserver ( 308 years ) :
https://www.openhub.net/p/geoserver

Here is Mapserver ( 63y) :
https://www.openhub.net/p/mapserver

You should also probably add PostGIS to that if you want an effective system (+80y ) :
https://www.openhub.net/p/postgis

But clearly the real answer would probably be : do not reinvent the wheel where opensource software already has solutions for your needs.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. You are right in saying that why reinvent the wheel but we have specific requirements where by we want to go down to minutes not hours of rendering high quality raster + vector data maps (using tiling system) with all the details like labels, different  features etc. on  them. And all the stories that I have read on the web regarding what people are doing to generate tiled maps are only about hours and days of rendering tiled maps which is kinda unacceptable in our case.

Comment: So you believe that you can do it 100 or 1000 times faster than servers like Mapnik, GeoServer, or MapServer? Your software will be popular once it is published. Out of curiosity, do you plan to use high-end graphics cards for rendering of where the superious speeed?

Comment: Then your question is not about software but infrastructure and refining your use case to be coherent with things doable, and your budget. You can render with mapnik the full world in minutes if you have a sufficient amount of server. Rendering is highly parallel. Rewriting the software thinking you can improve performance by 10-100 is a dangerous bet. And you have better chances improving the existing tools than writing your own.

Comment: Well @user30184 it will be little over ambitious to say that I'm gonna do 100 to 1000 times faster. It's just that I'm trying to collect some stats and based on that I will decide what is the best possible option, might try it as well since you know that whoever is using whatever technique everything is custom and unique in their case so it's all just a research at this time but you never know we might come up with something faster than the existing techniques.